# Time and Space Complexity of a Recursive Algorithm

Tags: time-complexity, space-complexity

Convert `n` to its English words representation, where 0 <= `n` < 1,000,000,000

**Python Solution:**

```
class Solution:
    def helper(self, n):
        ones = ['', 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine']
        teens = ['Ten', 'Eleven', 'Twelve', 'Thirteen', 'Fourteen', 'Fifteen', 'Sixteen', 'Seventeen', 'Eighteen', 'Nineteen']
        tens = ['', '', 'Twenty', 'Thirty', 'Forty', 'Fifty', 'Sixty', 'Seventy', 'Eighty', 'Ninety']

        res = ''
        if n < 10:
            res = ones[n]
        elif n < 20:
            res = teens[n - 10]
        elif n < 100:
            res = tens[n // 10] + ' ' + self.helper(n % 10)
        elif n < 1000:
            res = self.helper(n // 100) + ' Hundred ' + self.helper(n % 100)
        elif n < 1000000:
            res = self.helper(n // 1000) + ' Thousand ' + self.helper(n % 1000)
        elif n < 1000000000:
            res = self.helper(n // 1000000) + ' Million ' + self.helper(n % 1000000)
        return res.strip()


    def convert_to_word(self, n):
        if n == 0:
            return 'Zero'
        return self.helper(n)
```

I've been trying to calculate the time and space complexity of this solution. I've seen different answers. Some say that the time complexity is O(1) because the helper function is called a fixed number of times (even if n is a large number). Others say it's O(log(n)).

The space complexity seems to be O(1)?

I am so confused. Please help me clarify. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

On all inputs `n` that are larger than 1000000000, the function returns immediately with an empty string, without any computations or recursive calls. So of course the time complexity is O(1), likewise the space complexity (since what happens for smaller `n` is completely irrelevant).

The case would be different and more interesting if you removed the line

```
elif n < 1000000000
```

so that for large `n` you would get a (virtually) unbounded resulting string with an unbounded number of `Million`-substrings (ignoring the fact that integers have a maximum size on a real computer, and ignoring the fact that you would get nonsensical number words). In this case you would get the time complexity `O(log(n)^2)` (since you're concatenating `O(log n)` strings of length `O(log n)`) and space complexity `O(log n)` (because of the call stack for the recursive calls). The time complexity could easily be reduced to `O(log n)` by handling the string concatenations more efficiently.

---

#### Some additional explanation

It seems from the comments that it's not obvious why the time complexity is O(1). If we say that the time complexity *T(n)* is in O(1), that means that there exists a constant *c* and a constant *k* such that for all *n > k*, *T(n) <= c*.

In this example, choosing `c = 9` and `k = 0` does the trick, or alternatively choosing `c = 1 and k = 1000000000`, hence the time complexity is O(1). It should now also be clear that the following function is also O(1) (albeit with a very large hidden constant factor):

```
void f(int n) {
   if (n < 1000000000) {
      for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
         for(int k = 0; k < n; k++)
            print(i); 
      }
   }
   else print("");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If, let's say, I handle the string concatenations more efficiently (append/extend to a list and then join those strings), would the algorithm take **O(log n) time** (O(log n) for string concatenations + O(log n) for recursive calls = O(log n) overall) and **O(log n) space** (for recursive calls)? For, example, if n = 999,999,999.

Comment: Yes, but only if you remove the last condition on `n`, otherwise it's O(1).

Comment: Why it's O(1)?If n is larger than the last condition, then, yes, we return right away and it's O(1). But I can have different input, right? If I remove the last condition on n, I can still have different input. For example, if I delete the last condition and the input will be 999,999, then I'll have several recursive calls to the helper function. Wouldn't it take O(log n) time?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said: it's O(log n) time if you remove the last condition and join the strings more efficiently.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Are you saying that if I **won't** delete the last condition and my input will be, for example, 999,999, the time complexity will be O(1)?

Comment: Yes, the time complexity is O(1) if the code is exactly as you wrote it.

Comment: That's what I can't understand, honestly. How can it be constant if I have recursive calls? If n < 10 or n < 20, then yes, it's constant because there are no recursive calls for such a small input. But if, let's say, n = 856, I have recursive calls. Wouldn't it be O(log n)?

Comment: I added some explanation. I think it will become clearer if you read the definition of O(f) on Wikipedia first.

Comment: Thank you. Did I understand correctly that it's O(1) because the recursive calls won't go into "significant" depth?

Comment: No, even if you had an exponential recursion depth of `2^n` for all `n <1000000000` it would still be O(1). The behavior of the function for any finite number of inputs is completely irrelevant. Have you read and understood the formal definition of O(f)?

Comment: Yes, I've read about big-O notation. And I think I understood the meaning of it. I've been using it to calculate the complexity of my solutions for a while now. I have trouble understanding how to calculate the complexity of some of the recursive functions, though...